# How to determine the blog post to "Continue Reading" when my blog.ejs is rendered through the get route

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

I'm a beginner: just started learning server-side programming using nodejs. I have a blog site I developed with the help of Bootstrap. Now, I have index.js, welcome.ejs, header.ejs,and footer.ejs. No database yet; just working and learning the basics.

I can click on any "Continue reading" a-link in the welcome.ejs and the server (index.js) will take me to the blog.ejs.

welcome.ejs

`
Our latest...
...Common Mistake...
Nov 12
 90% of marriage relationships today fail because of the ladies. Though
this result can be argued by many but,... "

Continue reading


`

index.js

app.get("/blogs",(req,res)=>{      res.render("blogs.ejs"); });

But, the problem is that other posts have the same "Continue reading" that link to the same blog.ejs; hence, I don't know how to determine the blog post/article to show in the blog.ejs when a "Continue reading" is clicked.

I tried to capture the of that post in welcome.ejs into the server (index.js) and use it to determine the blog post or article to route in the blog.ejs.

index.js

app.get("/blogs",(req,res)=>{      const blogPost=req.body["h3"].innerHTML;      res.render("blogs.ejs", {postedBlog:blogPost});  });

Then in the blog.ejs, I tried to query the existence of the variable, postedBlog in index.js in order to know the right article to display in the blog.ejs.

blog.ejs

<% if (locals.postedBlog){%>                <%= postedBlog%>         <%} else{%>                Firehose       <%}%>

Comment: You can pass data to your views containing the article you want your users to read. In essence, you need to append the resource identifier to the link on continue reading so that your router can take it from the `req.params` object and that will determine which article to add along with the view. Can you post your actual code from the relevant ejs files and the index.js file so that someone can give you an example. Just edit the question as paste as formatted code blocks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @jQueeny. Your idea worked for me.
 I used 
app.get("/:id",(req,res)=>{
    const blogPost=req.params['id'];
    res.render("blogs.ejs", {postedBlog:blogPost});
});

Comment: @Community I hope to do that next time. I am just new here. Thanks a lot.